# Plotting a graph in a new tab using onclick of d3js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, plot, onclick

I have a plot which are is small in size in my home page and when i click on  the plot, i want it to open the plot in an enlarged size in a new tab.

I tried the following, but its just opening a new tab but did not plot anything.
Assume that vis is the element that contains the current plot and when vis is clicked, it should plot the same graph bigger in a new window.

The max value,data and date_array are all printed correctly, so there is no problem with the data.

```
               vis.on('click', function(){



                var newWindow = window.open('');
                console.log(data[0]);
                console.log(date_array);
                console.log(max_value);
                var vis1 = d3.select(newWindow.document.body),
                    WIDTH = 400,
                    HEIGHT = 150,
                    MARGINS = {
                        top: 10,
                        right: 10,
                        bottom: 10,
                        left: 100
                    },
                    xScale = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(date_array).rangePoints([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]),
                    yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([0, max_value]),
                    xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(xScale)

                    yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(yScale);

                vis1.append("svg:g")
                    .attr("class", "x axis")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ")")
                    .call(xAxis)


                vis1.append("svg:g")
                    .attr("class", "y axis")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (MARGINS.left) + ",0)")
                    .call(yAxis)

                var lineGen = d3.svg.line()
                    .x(function(d) {
                        return xScale(d.count);
                    })
                    .y(function(d) {
                        return yScale(d.param_perc);
                    })
                    .interpolate("basis");

                vis1.append('svg:path')
                    .attr('d', lineGen(data))
                    .attr('stroke', color)
                    .attr('stroke-width', 2)
                    .attr('fill', 'none')

                     })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to plot an svg you first need to insert an svg. Your code is appending `g`s and a `path` to the `body` but it is missing the containing `svg` element. This could easily be solved by adding

```
vis1 = vis1.append("svg");
```

This works for me in a boiled down [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/jtlT1AyDImT3HVEdwPZU?p=preview).

Comment: This is great, thank you. Is there any code we could add that might take that plot from the new window and put it in the original window (so we can swap between original and new)?